# Using Fragments instad of separated activities

Tags: android, memory-management, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

im going to write a little android app. Nothing complicated, with 6 "screens". 4 of them are on the same view navigation hierarchy level. 2 are subscreens of one of those 4.

For example screen A displays a list with information. By clicking on a list item the app will show screen A1. Screen A1 displays details about the previously selected list item. So Screen A1 is a subscreen of screen A. By clicking on the back button the app shows screen A.

Screen B has also a subscreen, called B1. The other screens are C and D which are on the same view navigation hierarchy as A and B (but not A1 and B1). So A, B, C, and D are on the top of the view navigation hierarchy. The App will start with displaying screen A. In the action bar (or in a sliding menu) you will find buttons to jump to screen B, C and D.

I hope you got an idea of what im trying to do. So normally I would say, every screen is a own activity. Im a big fan of fragments and i normally use them everywhere. In fact I caught myself implementing activities that contains only one fragment, that contains the main view layout. And I can say there is absolutely nothing wrong to do so (Fragments bring big advantages ... )

But now I wonder if it would be a good idea to use a single main activity and change only the fragments in this activity. So screen A, B, C, D, A1, B1 are Fragments instead of activities. So by navigating from Screen A to C I would simply replace fragment A with fragment C in the main activity (instead of starting a new Activity that contains the fragment C). The same way I would implement a navigation from screen A to subscreen A1.

So far I can't see nothing wrong with this approach. In my opinion it would be something like a ViewPager, just without swipe gestures to navigate between screens.

The only thing Im not sure about it (and thats my question) is the memory management. Whenever I do a replace fragment transaction (fragment manager) to navigate from screen A to B the fragment A should be destroyed and the memory should be garbage collected (somewhere in the future), right? When do I instantiate Fragment B? When the user clicks on the button to navigate to B (and repalce A)? Could this bring performance issues (time to instantiate the fragment)?

What if I set all fragments A, B, C, D, A1 and B1 to setRetainInstanceState(true)? Than the class member fields of each screen will be hold in the memory until the MainActivity is finished right?

Does anyone of you have experience with that?

A ViewPage uses some kind of "preloading" fragments and loads only the view layout of the next and previous fragment (setOffscreenPageLimit() )

Do you guys think I have to do something similar to avoid memory and performace issues?

Comment: Please don't prefix your question title with Android,the tag at the bottom is more then enough. As you didn't wrote anything until now there aren't any performance problems(and there shouldn't be any if you write the proper fragment code).